# Javascript scroller works on local server but not online (jsScroller.js)

Tags: javascript

I have recently made some minor edits to a website of mine that uses a javascript scroller in it (that i found onlin eyears ago) and suddently it's no longer working. I can't think what I would have changed. it's strange because it continues to work fine on my local server (MAMP) but no longer works on the web.

Here is a link to the page online where it is not working:

http://tinyurl.com/scrollernotworking

If it makes more sense to post the code here, here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/scroll.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" --><title>TEST SCROLLER ONLINE</title><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

<!-- InstanceParam name="id" type="text" value="staff" -->


<style type="text/css">
@import url(test.css);
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jsScroller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jsScrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var scroller  = null;
var scrollbar = null;
window.onload = function () {
  scroller  = new jsScroller(document.getElementById("Scroller"), 400, 200);
  scrollbar = new jsScrollbar (document.getElementById("Scrollbar-Container"), scroller, false);
}
</script>

</head>

<body id="staff">



            <div id="content">

                    <div id="Scroller">
                        <div class="Scroller-Container"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="text" -->
                        <div id="lipsum">
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur  posuere nisi sed tortor molestie sodales. In at turpis id nibh eleifend  porta. Sed risus dui, eleifend non sem eget, tempor adipiscing mauris.  In sodales sem vel commodo pretium. Phasellus vulputate velit a  imperdiet tristique. Nunc a lacus ut elit sagittis bibendum. Ut vel quam  nunc. Aenean hendrerit nulla eu ligula porttitor accumsan. </p>
                            <p> Duis turpis justo, commodo ac massa rhoncus, rhoncus semper massa.  Nullam faucibus leo ut tempor tempus. Mauris a elementum nibh, non  congue felis. Curabitur eu nibh mauris. Maecenas quis fringilla augue.  Morbi id malesuada nisl. Donec nec aliquam purus. Proin at malesuada  justo. Vivamus tempor velit lectus, a sagittis nisl mollis eu. Donec at  enim laoreet, rhoncus nulla posuere, consequat elit. Nam vel ante eros.  Phasellus laoreet tempus mattis. Phasellus a fringilla neque. Nulla  rutrum nibh quis malesuada sollicitudin. Etiam suscipit nibh eu  porttitor tristique. </p>
                          <p> Ut aliquam, diam sit amet dapibus imperdiet, nisl augue pharetra odio,  in interdum tortor quam non sem. Nulla molestie rhoncus sem eget  tincidunt. Sed vel velit fermentum, sagittis turpis vel, accumsan nibh.  Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce leo est, pharetra eu tortor non,  sollicitudin tempor ligula. Proin nec adipiscing erat, at suscipit  tellus. Nullam scelerisque porta iaculis. Cras est tortor, scelerisque  non vestibulum eu, pellentesque vel magna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis  in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; </p>
                            <h2> Heading Example 1</h2>
                            <p>ullam accumsan leo erat, in interdum quam luctus ac. In nulla mi,  sodales a aliquet at, gravida nec mauris. Quisque nec interdum diam.  Etiam fermentum pulvinar dolor in cursus. Ut hendrerit porta  ullamcorper. In lobortis neque sed sem condimentum, quis feugiat elit  consequat. In eu erat mi. </p>
                            <p> Nulla ornare egestas libero nec tempus. Sed id ornare enim. Maecenas  pharetra massa sed augue sodales vestibulum. Suspendisse potenti. Duis  et accumsan justo, a dictum velit. Aliquam ultricies eleifend sagittis.  Cras in risus est. Sed molestie urna elit, eget varius magna euismod sit  amet. </p>
                            <h2> Heading Example 2</h2>
                            <p>Sed turpis elit, hendrerit eu diam nec, vulputate laoreet lectus.  Pellentesque volutpat erat vel nisl tincidunt feugiat. Vestibulum quam  sem, condimentum eu ultrices eu, scelerisque a turpis. Duis condimentum  dictum lectus, in ornare lacus vehicula posuere. Ut venenatis urna ac  euismod bibendum. Aenean eu arcu cursus, fermentum mi at, interdum  libero. Praesent tincidunt tortor eu ultrices viverra. Fusce in velit a  mi euismod mollis. Suspendisse venenatis congue justo, at luctus enim.  Aliquam nec volutpat erat. </p>
                            <p> Fusce fringilla sapien magna, ac bibendum turpis condimentum sed. Donec  posuere, nunc et rhoncus dapibus, velit magna semper leo, sed commodo  odio enim feugiat magna. Nam aliquet turpis eu lectus ultricies, eget  tempor urna eleifend. Aliquam sit amet magna volutpat nunc pretium  accumsan quis nec erat. Fusce volutpat porta ipsum nec adipiscing. Donec  eu enim molestie ante sollicitudin consequat eget at arcu. Ut id ante  eget metus porttitor imperdiet. Fusce faucibus nunc vel elit convallis,  eu iaculis nulla semper. Vivamus ullamcorper diam libero, non dignissim  dolor vestibulum et. Vivamus in volutpat nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat.  Maecenas massa massa, congue quis tortor at, interdum laoreet augue.  Aenean mattis lacus dui, quis ullamcorper massa tincidunt quis. </p>
                          <h2> Heading Example 3</h2>
                          <p>Nullam sit amet porta urna. Pellentesque quis tristique diam. Sed ac  porta urna. Nunc porttitor eget nibh id ornare. Duis a nunc a purus  ultrices pretium eu et lacus. Duis auctor condimentum ligula, nec  commodo lectus eleifend sed. Cras varius adipiscing feugiat. Mauris  posuere sem a ultrices adipiscing. Sed id lectus tortor. Aenean vitae  rhoncus turpis, a vulputate purus. Etiam rutrum nulla sit amet urna  hendrerit bibendum. Donec laoreet porttitor risus nec porttitor. </p>
                        </div>
                          <div id="generated"></div>
                        <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div><!--close Scroller-Container-->
                    </div><!--close Scroller-->

                    <div id="Scrollbar-Container">
                        <div class="Scrollbar-Track">
                        <div class="Scrollbar-Handle"></div><!--close Scrollbar-Handle-->
                        </div><!--close Scrollbar-Track-->
                    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="homepage-calltoActions" --><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                    </div><!--close Scrollbar-Container-->

            </div><!--close Content-->






</body>

<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

and here is my css:

```
html, body {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        }

    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:50px;
        background-color:#676B62;
        line-height:135%;
        font-family:Verdana,Arial,  Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#333;

    }

    p {
    margin:0 0 15px 0;
    line-height:145%;
    }


    h2 {
    font-size:1.1em;
    margin:0 0 9px 0;
    text-transform:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:140%;
    }


    #content {
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    min-height:469px; /** added min to test ****/
    margin:0;
    padding:50px;
    background-color:#FFC;
    }



    /*************** Scroller CSS **************/

    #Scroller {
        text-align:left;
        font-size:12px;
        position:absolute;
        width: 590px;
        height: 375px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin:0;
        line-height:135%;
        /*background-color:#6CF;*/
    }


    .Scroller-Container {
     position: absolute;

    }

    .Scrollbar-Track {
      width: 20px; 
      height: 375px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color:#ccd59a;
      margin:0 0 0 605px;
    }

    .Scrollbar-Handle {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px; 
      left: 0px;
      width: 20px; 
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #81943B;
      background-image:url(images/site/scrollbar-handle.gif);
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

and the javascript hasn't been chaged by me since it was original working perfectly, but you can see it linked to in the head of the linked page above.

I'd be grateful for any help anyone can offer!

Thanks so much in advance... I've spent hours trying to figure out what i might possibly have accidentally changed, but to no avail :(

Comment: have you uploaded the js file to server is its path correct what is the error you see in console?

Answer (score 1):

I can see this error in my console when I opened the link `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsScroller is not defined`  that means that you have not included the js file or your path to js file is wrong. correct that it will surely work.

Comment: Yes you might have incorrectly included the js , try use the cdn